# Rails UrlGeneration Error on form_for after upgrade to 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, form-for

I just upgraded rails from 4.0 to 4.2 and it seems to have caused an error in one of my form_fors.  Now when I visit the new view, I get:

Error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError at /billing/providers/new
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"billing/provider_agencies", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

View (error from this line):

```
= form_for @provider_agency, url: billing_provider_agency_path(@provider_agency) do |f|
  ...
```

Routes:

```
namespace :billing do
  resources :provider_agencies, path: "providers" do
    resources :invoices
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
class Billing::ProviderAgenciesController < BillingController
  before_action :set_provider_agency, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    ...
  end

  def show
    @users = @provider_agency.users
  end

  def destroy
    ...
  end

  def new
    @provider_agency = Agency::Provider.new
  end

  def create
    ...
  end

  def edit
    ...
  end

  def update
    ...
  end

  protected
  def provider_agency_params
    params.require(:agency_provider).permit(:id, :name,...
    ...
    ])
  end

  def set_provider_agency  
    @provider_agency = @agency.agencies.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I had to define the url in the form_for because of the way I namespace the resources in my routes.  Defining that url in the form_for used to work in any view including new. Now the new view seems to be calling the show action, and looking for the @provider_agency that hasn't been created/saved yet.  To be clear, this breaks the new view but all other view's still work.

I went back to check the commits and none of these files have changed, the error simply begins when I upgrade to Rail 4.2.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:

Here is the relevant portion of my rake routes too:

```
billing_provider_agencies     GET    /billing/providers(.:format)           billing/provider_agencies#index
                              POST   /billing/providers(.:format)           billing/provider_agencies#create
new_billing_provider_agency   GET    /billing/providers/new(.:format)       billing/provider_agencies#new
edit_billing_provider_agency  GET    /billing/providers/:id/edit(.:format)  billing/provider_agencies#edit
billing_provider_agency       GET    /billing/providers/:id(.:format)       billing/provider_agencies#show
                              PATCH  /billing/providers/:id(.:format)       billing/provider_agencies#update
                              PUT    /billing/providers/:id(.:format)       billing/provider_agencies#update
                              DELETE /billing/providers/:id(.:format)       billing/provider_agencies#destroy
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue.  I'm using a custom ActiveModel form object for the `form_for`, and since upgrading from 4.1 to 4.2 Rails is generating the route differently -- it has the HTTP method correct, but the endpoint is wrong -- it's submitting a PATCH to `/users` when it should be going to `/users/:id`, as appropriate.  This worked fine in 4.1 by delegating `#to_model` on the form object to the AR model I was wrapping, but now I'm getting a routing error.  Did you ever figure out the issue?

Comment: Ah, just stepped through the source and found a bug that addressed my issue.  [This commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/3efd90ac5b15d376bc5780d08d6e07d5a2b50ff1) fixed it, but it came in after the 4.2.0 release, and they haven't shipped their next patch release yet.  IDK if that would fix your issue, but it might be worth running against rails master branch to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

I modified the form_for syntax little bit.

For nested model,old syntax:

```
form_for(@child, url: parent_child_path(@parent,@child))
```

to newer syntax

```
form_for([@parent,@child])
```

For independent model

```
form_for(@model, url: model_path(@model))
```

to

```
form_for(@model)
```

Refer [here](http://localhost:4000/2015/10/url_generation_error_after_upgrading_rails/)